# Xcode gives "spotlight quit unexpectedly" error message

Tags: xcode, macos

After updating to the newest version of Xcode 12, I started getting a "spotlight quit unexpectedly" error message. I uninstalled Xcode and the error message went away, but when I look in Launchpad the Xcode icon is still there and can't be deleted. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Run `killall Dock` or drag the icon out from the Dock.

Comment: It isn't in the dock. It does however show up in Launchpad as if it is still installed, but if I click the icon it says "Required content for platform tvOS Simulator is missing Please reinstall Xcode"

Comment: Oh my bad. Is it in the /Applications folder? Have you tried a restart? Just search the whole Mac for "xcode" with something like easyfind https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12

Comment: Ok, that did it. I held the icon in Launchpad and thought that by clicking the little x it was deleted, but then I opened Finder and it was still in the Applications folder so after dragging it to the trash, and emptying it, it's gone. I'm still getting used to Macs after using windows for 20 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking "x" on the jiggling icons in the Launchpad has not been a robust method to delete apps, in my experience. Some apps are root-owned (check by `ls -la`) so this method never even prompts for root password, let alone deleting the apps.

Best way is to use uninstaller or in-app buttons to uninstall it. This cleans up the contents in `~/Library` or `/Library` and any Launchdaemons or Launchagents.

For Xcode, no such thing is there, so move Xcode app to Trash using Finder.
Also delete `~/Library/Developer` if you'd like.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/how-to-show-hidden-files-on-mac-without-terminal/264473#264473